# How can make custom auth in laravel 8 with pre-existing table?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, web, eloquent

How to create custom authentication in laravel 8 with **preexisting table** (but with table name **Users_system** not **Users**) and this table (Users_system) is full of data and does not have the same fields as Users for laravel?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `config/auth.php` file. In this file you can define your source. From the `auth.php` file:

> If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.